# WPF Style Selected Items of ListBox Using an ItemsPanelTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How can I style the selected items in this listbox?

```
<ListBox x:Name="AssetTypeListBox" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
             <UniformGrid Columns="6"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
</ListBox>
```

I have tried

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#F15025"/>
```

and

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#F15025"/>
```

But they don't seem to affect the selected items as I would expect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the colour of the selection, then the easiest way is to set the solidcolorbrush as a resource on your Listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="AssetTypeListBox" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.Resources>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#F15025"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#F15025"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
             <UniformGrid Columns="6"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
</ListBox>
```

If you're wanting to customise the style of the ***selection*** of an item in the listbox, such as changing the selection colour or completely restyling the look of a selected item, you need to look at the ItemContainerStyle property.

The ItemsPanelTemplate doesn't affect this - it simply sets the ItemsControl type that should layout and present the items - such as a StackPanel or UniformGrid.

The basic hierarchy (with a pinch of salt) of a ListBox is:

- ListBox

  - ItemsPanelTemplate (StackPanel by default)

    - ItemsContainerStyle (Selection highlighting is here)

      - ItemTemplate (You define the content of your list item here)

The differences between ItemTemplates and ItemsContainerStyle are covered here:
[What's the difference between ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle in a WPF ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546143/whats-the-difference-between-itemtemplate-and-itemcontainerstyle-in-a-wpf-listb)